# Show that function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

If $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=z_{0}$, and $\left|f^{(n)}\left(z_{0}\right)\right| \leq n^{k}$ for each $n$ (k fixed), show that $f(z)$ is actually an entire function..

**Attempt**:

Since $f$ is analytic at circle $C$ centered at $z_0$ with radius $r$, we can write $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z - z_0)^n$ for $z\in C$.

Then, $|f(z)| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}|z - z_0|^n$ and by ratio test, radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{n!}|z - z_0|^n$ is $R=\infty$, so it is uniformly continuous for all $z$, as well as $f$.

How can we conclude from here that $f$ itself is entire?

Comment: I feel like some global condition is missing. Being analytic at $z_0$ doesn't say anything about the behaviour at, say, $z_0+1$. It doesn't even have to be continuous there. In fact, you haven't even said that it's defined there. What's the domain of $f$?

Comment: @Arthur The problem is from Ponnusamy Silverman, Complex Variables book. I think problem should be "there exists an entire function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)$ is identical to $f(z)$ on the small neighborhood of $z_0$."

Comment: That sounds a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you demonstrated, the radius of convergence of the power series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z - z_0)^n$ is infinity. It follows that $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z - z_0)^n$ is an entire function.

Also $f(z) = F(z) $ in $U_r(z_0)$. So $f$ is the restriction of an entire function. In other words, $f$ can be *extended holomorphically* to an entire function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now clearly.